# how to set default version in mvn pom

Tags: maven, pom.xml

H, I have a multi project that have inner dependencies and I use ${project.version} parameter to the dependencies. I want to set a default version that if the version of the specific artifact doesn't extrinsic he will use the default version.

Comment: Yes, also in google. You find similar question?

Comment: @yiaca I don't understand the logic you want to have. How can a version you reference not exist?

Comment: Without some clarification I doubt this question can be answered.

Comment: I have a complicated project, that contains 10 repositories that depend on each other. so I want the version to be dynamic. So if there is an artifact with this version- use this artifact, other ways, use the default version. But I'm not sure it's possible in maven

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You cannot have dynamic versions. The only thing that comes close are version ranges (like `[1.0, 2.0)`), but they fell out of fashion.

I still cannot really imagine a case in which this would be useful. First of all, if you have a list of 10 repositories you can just look up if a version exists or not. Why should it exist "sometimes"?

Secondly, if you have a "default version", why not just always use that? What do you gain from having another possible version?

Comment: I have a bb repo and  I want to set the version to included the branch name and test the changes that I did in this branch. But as you said, its possible.